# Update element on every Ajax success response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a function that loops through an array and calls a php script for each object of the array. The php script is getting the Lat/Lng from google maps api so i need to throttle the api calls. The list can be long (currently 300). I want to update the user as the script is running.

In my success callback I can console log every response but the element I want to update for the user only gets updated once.

Is there a way to update the user after each successful response?

here is my function:

```
$('#agents-lat-lng').click(function() {
    
    var data = {
      'action': 'getLatLng'
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: ajax_url,
      type: 'post',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){

        for ( var i = 0, l = response.query.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        
          $.when(updateLatLngDB(response.query[i]))
          .done(function(dataFromResponses){
          
            console.log('1 ', dataFromResponses[0])
          
          }).fail(function(response){
          
            console.error(response);
          
          });
        
        }
        
      },
      error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
        
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
      
      }
    })

  })
```

Here is the second function:

```
function updateLatLngDB(query) {

    var deferred = new $.Deferred()
    var dataFromResponses = []
    var count = 0

      var data = {
        'action': 'updateLatLng',
        'agent': query
      }

      $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(response){

          count++
          console.log('count ', count)

          $('#process-upload-response').text(count)
          
          dataFromResponses.push(response)

        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
          
          console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
          deferred.reject(response)
          
          $('#process-upload-response').html(textStatus, errorThrown)

        }
      })

    deferred.resolve(dataFromResponses)
    return deferred.promise()
  
  }
```

I have tried everything from Deferred to setTimout but I can not get #process-upload-response to update as each item in the array gets processed. It only updates after all the responses are complete.

UPDATE: I have been able to make it work by adding this to the for loop

```
(function(i){

            window.setTimeout(function(){
              
              promises.push(updateLatLngDB(response.query[i],response.query.length));

            }, i * 1000);

          }(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't keep state between calls to updateLatLngDB function and also you resolve the value with empty array because you don't call the resolve outside of async call.

If I understand this is what you want:

```js
    $.ajax({
      url: ajax_url,
      type: 'post',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){

        
        var promises = [];
        var updateLatLngDB = countRequests(0);

        for ( var i = 0, l = response.query.length; i < l; i++ ) {
          // collect promises
          promises.push(updateLatLngDB(response.query[i]));
        
        }
        // when all request are done execute done
        $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
            var dataFromResponses = arguments;

            console.log('1 ', dataFromResponses[0])
          
        }).fail(function(response){
          
            console.error(response);
          
        });
        
      },
      error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
        
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
      
      }
    })

// keep count in closure
function countRequests(count) {
   return function updateLatLngDB(query) {
      var deferred = new $.Deferred();
      var data = {
        'action': 'updateLatLng',
        'agent': query
      }
      

      $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(response){

          count++
          console.log('count ', count)

          $('#process-upload-response').text(count)
          
          dataFromResponses.push(response);
          
          deferred.resolve(response);

        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
          
          console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
          deferred.reject(response)
          
          $('#process-upload-response').html(textStatus, errorThrown)

        }
      })

    
    return deferred.promise()
  
  };
}
```

NOTE: that if you don't want all request to be done in parallel you will need to create async loop I like to write them like this (with async/await it's simpler because you can create normal while loop instead):

```js
var promises = [];
var i = 0; = response.query.length;
(function loop() {
   
    if (i < len) {
        var promise = updateLatLngDB(response.query[i++]);
        promises.push(promise);
        promise.then(loop);
    } else {
        $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
            var dataFromResponses = arguments;

            console.log('1 ', dataFromResponses[0])
          
        }).fail(function(response){
          
            console.error(response);
          
        });
    }
})();
```

with this you will be able to delay each request (if this is what you want).

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I still only get the final result printed to the page instead of a count

Comment: @Jason are you sure you have more then one item in `response.query` array? I can mock ajax request and show you that this works if you show how your data look like.

Comment: I found a way to make it work. see my update. I added that in the for loop

Comment: Do you see the new section titled UPDATE?

Comment: Ah it looks like it has to be approved first

Comment: @Jason I see pending edit in my anwser, if you have better solution you should not edit my code create your own answer and edit the question.

Comment: Ya, I see what I did. I put the update in the wrong section. One sec and I will correct this